# Abstract Method and Classes C#

Tags: c#, class, abstract

I am trying to make a code wich is based around abstract methods and classes in C#, but I can't figure out why my code does not work.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication16
{
    abstract class ICTcampus
    {
        public int addNumbers(int number1, int number2)
        {
            return number1 + number2;
        }

        public abstract void multiplyNumbers(int number1, int number2)
        {

        }

        public class Derivedclass : ICTcampus
        {
            public override int multiplyNumbers(int number1, int number2)
            {
                return number1 * number2;
            }
        }

        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {

                Derivedclass obj = new Derivedclass();
                int add = obj.addNumbers(2, 3);
                Console.Write(" addition is :{0}", add);
                // Console.Write(" multiplication is :{0}", obj.multiplyNumbers(2, 3));

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Not working" isn't a very good problem description. Try describing what your actual issue is.

Comment: In C# `abstract` methods cannot have body (`{}`). If you want to have a function with body it should be `virtual`

Comment: abstracts do not have code bodies...remove the brackets....public abstract void multiplyNumbers(int number1, int number2); And your overrride returns an int when the adstract is void!

Comment: Your `multiplyNumbers` method is declared as returning `void`, but it should be declared as returning `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace ConsoleApplication16
{
    public abstract class ICTcampus
    {
        public int addNumbers(int number1, int number2)
        {
            return number1 + number2;
        }

        public abstract int multiplyNumbers(int number1, int number2);

    }
    public class Derivedclass : ICTcampus
    {
        public override int multiplyNumbers(int number1, int number2)
        {
            return number1 * number2;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Derivedclass obj = new Derivedclass();
            int add = obj.addNumbers(2, 3);
            Console.Write(" addition is :{0}", add);
            // Console.Write(" multiplication is :{0}", obj.multiplyNumbers(2, 3));

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because your multiplynumber function shouldn't be abstract but virtual. If you want to leave it abstract then you should remove brackets and remove it's empty implementation